update the array in useEffect inside the map() loop onchange event input number react
I have input number in which I specify a number that stands for the number of rendered components. For this I have two states with a number and an array. In the array I just pass one value with id.
The code in useEffect is not working correctly. When I click on button up in input number, the Item are not added to the array. And when I click on button down, the items are not deleted.
Where did I go wrong here?
It should also be localStorage in the code.
const [Quantity, setQuantity] = useState('0')
const [Arr, setArr] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  [...Array(parseInt(Quantity))].map((_, i) => {
    setArr((prev) => {
      const Item = { id: i };
      localStorage.setItem("LSKey", JSON.stringify([...prev, Item]))
      return [...prev, Item];
    });
  });
}, [])

<input type="number" value={Quantity || ""} min={0} onChange={(event) => {
    setQuantity(event.target.value)
}} />

render components
Arr.map((Item) => (
  <Components key={Item.id} id={Item.id} />
))


Why are you using Array.prototype.map() when you don't care about the result?

The main issue is your effect hook only runs once on mount due to its empty dependencies array.
You'll want to depend on Quantity and only update state / localStorage after you've constructed the new array.
const [Quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0); // use an actual number, not a string
const [Arr, setArr] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const arr = Array.from({ length: Quantity }, (_, id) => ({ id }));
  localStorage.setItem('LSKey', JSON.stringify(arr));
  setArr(arr); // no need to use the previous value
}, [Quantity]); // set Quantity as an effect dependency

You can also use valueAsNumber to avoid parseInt()...
<input
  type="number"
  value={Quantity}
  min="0"
  onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
/>


It's working well! I studied the code and figured out how it works! Thank you!

I have to use parseInt() because I get the value from the local storage keys. if that key exists and has a value. But valueAsNumber is a good move!
